# Kotlin shuffle a list and validate list value with user value

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a list that holds string values as directions, for each time is started is shuffle the list

```
val directions = mutableListOf("left","right","up","down")
directions.shuffle()
```

I am running a continuous loop to check if the percentage value has grown to a certain point before breaking the loop

```
if(progress != 100){
  //continue until progress is 100
}
```

I send the instructions to the user and if they match the progress value increases

```
when(directions){
    "left" -> {
      // print direction to the user then check if followed
      if(checkLeftDirection() == "left"){
      // increment progress then remove left from the list
      directions.remove("left")
      progress +=10
    }
    // other directions
    else -> {
      //the loop always ends here
    }
}
```

`I want to send a list of random directions to the user and for each check if the user was correct and if the user is correct for a given direction then remove that direction from the list and send another random direction to the user.`

what happens is the loop runs and does nothing and just goes to the else statement, it loops all directions then ends at the else statement,

**UPDATE**

here is the loop

```
if (progress != 100) {
    for (item in directions) {
      when(item){
    "left" -> {
      // print direction to the user then check if followed
      if(checkLeftDirection() == item){
      // increment progress then remove left from the list
      directions.remove(item)
      progress +=10
    }
    // other directions
    else -> {
      //the loop always ends here
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `when` is not a loop, it is the equivalent of `switch` in other languages.

Comment: Your code shouldn't even compile like that. `directions` is a list and you are checking on `when(directions){` , which could never be a string. I suppose you might want `when(directions.first()){` maybe.

Comment: i have added my for loop on the question

Comment: I suppose it simply means `checkLeft()` returns false. Also, if it did go in there it will crash on `directions.remove(item)` because you can't modify a collection while iterating through it like that

Comment: what is the best practise i can do in such a case @IvoBeckers

Comment: It's hard to say because to me the use case is a bit unclear actually. Also, I actually don't see how it even ever is possible to get in the `else` if all directions are covered, and the list can't contain any other strings

Comment: I am checking face liveness using googles mlkit now i want send directions to the user but at random, if i do it manually it works but the random sending is the work that does not work as show above,